# Get the current facebook application ID is visited by the user using facebook C# dk

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I Have More than One Face Book ApplicationUsing the same Solution what i need is to get the current apid visited by the user using facebook C# sdk.
thanks in advance

Comment: Is this on a Facebook fan page?

Comment: yes it is within a facebook fan page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store the facebook application settings in DB then when the use r enter your facebook application get the id from the url using http.context.request.url or something like that where you can load your settings abon the app ID